# wordpress not displaying my form

Tags: forms

When I create a page with the content as      `[contact-form-7 id="199" title="Untitled"]` , it displays the form,
but when I use it as

```
<div class="first"><?php $recentProjects = get_post('275'); echo $recentProjects->post_content; ?> </div>
```

it is not working. It is displaying  `[contact-form-7 id="199" title="Untitled"]` instead of form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is correct behaviour. A simple `echo` will just return the field from the DB, unmodified.

if you want to render the shortcode try

```
<div class="first"><?php $recentProjects = get_post('275'); echo do_shortcode($recentProjects->post_content); ?> </div>
```

Comment: Really saved my time.thx a lot.